# Is it possible to use VBScript or JScript to instantiate SharePoint objects?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, vbscript

I want to be able to run VBScript or JScript on a server using cscript.exe to manipulate SharePoint through the object model.

For example, to update the log file location:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDiagnosticsService serv = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDiagnosticsService();
serv.LogLocation = @"E:\";
serv.Update();
```

Is it possible to do this?

I know I would need to run this code using a farm admin account. I don't have access to PowerShell (yet), and I don't want to have to compile dozens of small command line utilities to get this done, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OTTOMH, you could probably create [COM-callable wrappers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx) for the classes you need, if you have relatively simple needs.  My guess is that this will be more trouble than it's worth and that some small console apps would be a better use of your time, if you can't use PowerShell.